# iOS - Setting image src in javascript IPA build with cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, image, cordova, camera

I have a javascript application for iOS where I take photos and I would like to show them in a image component.

```
{
            xtype: 'image',
            itemId: 'camaraFoto1',
            id: 'camaraFoto1',c
            src: 'img/camara.png',
            reference: 'camaraFoto1',
            cls: 'imagen_capturada'
}
```

Once I take the photo, it is stored in a temp directory (cordova.file.tempDirectory) but this directory gets empty when I logout so I can´t use it cause I want persistence.

So I tried to move the photo to other directory (cordova.file.dataDirectroy) and then set the correct src to the image but the image component doesn´t load the image. What could be the problem?

This is part of the code where I take the photo and set the src to the image:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(me.photoSuccess, me.photoFailure, {
    quality: quality1,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,  //DATA_URL
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType:  navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: targetWidth1,
    targetHeight: targetHeight1,
    correctOrientation : correctOrientation1
});
```

```
photoSuccess: function (tempImage) {

        const newBaseFilesystemPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                  tempImage,
                  function(fileEntry){
                        newFileUri  = newBaseFilesystemPath;
                        newFileName =  tempImage.substr(tempImage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + ".spc";
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newFileUri,
                                function(dirEntry) {
                                    // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                                    fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newFileName,
                                    function ok() {
                                        var img = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#camaraFoto1")[0];
                                        img.setSrc(newBaseFilesystemPath + newFileName );

...
```

Note: if I don´t move the photo from the tempDirectory all this issue works and I can see the image on the component.

These is the full root when I use tempDirectory and dataDirectory. First one works, second one doesn`t:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/827A7500-309C-4521-BC0F-303D6D16AE3D/tmp/cdv_photo_1589965037.jpg

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9E3095A3-4D87-493B-A13D-398051179B54/Library/NoCloud/cdv_photo_1590070416.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the cordova preference in your `config.xml` file, such as

```xml
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync" />
```

and

```xml
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

as stated on cordova docs, see [iOS Persistent storage location](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#ios-persistent-storage-location)